# Django why use inline in admin?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Just starting out with Django and I have a basic model for creating blog posts. Basic idea is I want each post to have multiple tags and hopefully later use those for filtering my posts.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-pub_date"]
```

on my admin side I'm wondering the best way be able to add posts. I've been reading a bunch of threads where people suggest to use an inline style for manytomany relationships, but don't see the difference between that and just editing the object.

So why go with this

```
class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post.tags.through
    extra = 1

class newsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    inlines = [TagInline]     
    exclude = ('tags',)

admin.site.register(Post, newsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

over this?

```
class newsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
   prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Post, newsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

Comment: Inline models are soemtimes called "weak references". They are models that only make sense in the context of a parent model. That's what the inline admin interface provides - editing of a related model in the context of a parent.

Answer (score 3):

An inline has (almost?) no benefit over a regular field in the case of a default `through` model for a `ManyToManyField`. But consider the following (simplified) model:

```
STATUS = (
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comment = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS)
```

The primary objective is no longer to connect the right comment to the right post. However, it would be very convenient to moderate all comments on a post on the edit page of the post itself, instead of moderating each comment on a separate page. An inline allows you to change the status of each comment on a single page.

Basically, if you just want to select which items to relate to your primary object, an inline isn't needed. If you need to frequently edit the objects related to your primary object, an inline provides a huge convenience.